# select * from products where two different

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for terribel title but I hope some can help

I just made a second brand, because I want mulitple brands in my product.

Therefore I had this to get 1 brand:

```
$get_brand_pro = "select * from products where product_brand='$brand_id'";
```

But I'm now wondering how to get more,
I tried this:

```
$get_brand_pro = "select * from products where product_brand='$brand_id' AND product_brand1='$brand_id'";
```

But it wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your table

Comment: Not AND use OR. `product_brand` cannot be `a and b` but it can be `a OR b`

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly! That worked perfectly

Comment: Argh, normalise your database properly :P

Comment: Use [paremetrized queries](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to avoid sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use OR not AND if you want both

```
$get_brand_pro = "select * from products where product_brand='$brand_id' OR product_brand1='$brand_id'";
```

Comment: even better would be use IN like `$brand_id IN (product_brand,product_brand1)`

Comment: ^ this as well for a shorter query.